# Output the dropped/excluded observation in Proc GLIMMIX - SAS

Tags: sas

When I run a proc glimmix in SAS, sometimes it drops observations.
How do I get the set of dropped/excluded observations or maybe the set of included observations so that I can identify the dropped set?

My current Proc GLIMMX code is as follows-

> ```
>      %LET EST=inputf.aarefestimates;
> ```

```
     %LET MODEL_VAR3 = age Male Yearc2010 HOSPST
                Hx_CTSURG Cardiogenic_Shock COPD MCANCER DIABETES;



    data work.refmodel;
    set inputf.readmref;
    Yearc2010 = YEAR - 2010;         
    run;

   PROC GLIMMIX DATA = work.refmodel NOCLPRINT MAXLMMUPDATE=100;
  CLASS  hospid HOSPST(ref="xx");
  ODS OUTPUT PARAMETERESTIMATES = &est (KEEP=EFFECT ESTIMATE STDERR);
  MODEL RADM30 = &MODEL_VAR3 /Dist=b LINK=LOGIT SOLUTION; 
  XBETA=_XBETA_;
  LINP=_LINP_;
  RANDOM INTERCEPT/SUBJECT= hospid SOLUTION; 
  OUTPUT OUT =  inputf.aar
    PRED(BLUP ILINK)=PREDPROB PRED(NOBLUP ILINK)=EXPPROB;
 ID XBETA LINP hospst hospid Visitlink Key RADM30;
 NLOPTIONS TECH=NRRIDG;

 run;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It drops records with missing values in any variable you're using in the model, in a CLASS, BY, MODEL, RANDOM statement.  So you can check for missing among those variables to see what you get. Usually the output data set will also indicate this by not having predictions for the records that are not used.

You can run the code below.

```
*create fake data;
data heart;set sashelp.heart; ;run;

*Logistic Regression model, ageCHDdiag is missing ;
proc logistic data=heart; 
class sex / param=ref;
model status(event='Dead') = ageCHDdiag height weight diastolic;
*generate output data;
output out=want p=pred;
run;

*explicitly flag records as included;
data included;
set want;
if missing(pred) then include='N'; else include='Y';
run;

*check that Y equals total obs included above;
proc freq data=included;
table include;
run;
```

The output will show:

```
                 The LOGISTIC Procedure

                        Model Information

          Data Set                      WORK.HEART
          Response Variable             Status
          Number of Response Levels     2
          Model                         binary logit
          Optimization Technique        Fisher's scoring


              Number of Observations Read        5209
              Number of Observations Used        1446
```

And then the PROC FREQ will show:

```
                        The FREQ Procedure

                                       Cumulative    Cumulative
   include    Frequency     Percent     Frequency      Percent
   ƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒƒ
   N              3763       72.24          3763        72.24
   Y              1446       27.76          5209       100.00
```

And 1,446 records are included in both of the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered my question.
The code line - 
   OUTPUT OUT =  inputf.aar
gives the output of the model.  This table includes all the observations used in the proc statement.  So I can match the data in this table to my input table and find the observations that get dropped.

@REEZA - I already looked for missing values for all the columns in the data. Was not able to identify the records there are getting dropped by only identifying the no. of records with missing values.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: If you have answered your own question that is great!  Read up on self answers -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer